# How to make ftp work on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ftp

I have tried many answers but I was unable to make ftp work on my ubuntu 14.04.ftp works with localhost but not with other ip's

Whenever I try to use

```
>ftp <ip-address>
```

I get this error

```
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

I have installed ftpd and ftpd this is output of

**`dpkg -l | grep 'ftp'`**

```
ii  ftp                                                   0.17-28                                             amd64        classical file transfer client
ii  ftpd                                                  0.17-34                                             amd64        File Transfer Protocol (FTP) server
rc  vsftpd                                                3.0.2-1ubuntu2.14.04.1                              amd64        lightweight, efficient FTP server written for security
```

Also This is the output of

**`iptables -L`**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

output of

**`netstat -l | grep ftp`**

```
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN
```

Please help me!

Comment: Have you checked if ftp server is installed? of is it running? try to run this command dpkg -l | grep -i ftp tell me whats the result

Comment: Do you want to connect to a remote server or you want to allow ftp connections to your machine?

Comment: Do you know of an ftp server which is certain to work (ie, it work on another system in the same LAN as your system)? Could you try with such a server?

Comment: actually I am trying to connect to my friends laptop..both laptops are in same network even my friend can ftp to my laptop but I cant!

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if the ftp server is running:

```bsh
ps aux | grep ftp
```

If not, see if you can start/stop or restart the service:

```bsh
sudo service ftpd stop && sudo service ftpd start
```

Or:

```bsh
sudo service ftpd restart
```

You can also check to see whether `ftpd` is listening on the correct port:

```bsh
netstat -l | grep ftp
```

The output should show `ftpd` listening on port 21 (standard ftp port).

Comment: netstat output added to question!

Comment: Also `sudo service ftpd restart` says ftpd:unrecognised service

Comment: It appears as though the suggested means of running an FTP server on Ubuntu, is to use either vsftpd - http://askubuntu.com/questions/323868/how-do-i-install-a-ftp-server -  or proftpd http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_14.04&p=ftp&f=2

Comment: The output of `dpkg` shows that `vsftpd` was installed at one stage, but removed ('rc') ... did you try and follow one of the other guides?

Comment: the answer given in the link doesn't work for me...I think something else is causing this problem.. Check my output of `netstat` looks weird!

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the daemon in the standard `ftpd` package is meant to be running, but the output is correct - it shows that a process called `ftpd` is listening globally (`*.*`) on the standard ftp port. To confirm this, you can add the -n flag to netstat - `netstat -ln` - and this should show port 21 listening.

Comment: From my own experience, you're better of using proftpd, since it's a trusted and proven product. It will also allow you to use `sftp`, which uses ssh under the hood, and is far more secure than standard ftp, which is generally known as insecure (partly because it uses plaintext for data transfer)