# How to add FTP and SSH acces to Ubuntu?

Tags: ssh, ftp

Day2 of my Ubuntu Desktop experience:
Got a simpleNodeJS page (Hello World) page working and i even could reach it via my home-network. Now I want to add FTP and SSH access, because this Ubuntu pc need to function as a NodeJS testserver, before i will rent a dedicated server. So i need to develope and excercise my SSH skills.

I have searched in the software centre but could not find it. I suppose i need to do something like 
apt-get SSH/FTP
But i do not understand what exactly to do, when it isn't found there?

May thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yesss! Pitty it wont be shown when just search for SSH. You also know a phrase for FTP?

Comment: I have installed ssh and indeed i saw an included ftp, so i wil try that one. I installed via software centre not apt, is there any difference between them? U can write your answer, so i can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: and btw, how do i make sure technical results will be visible?

Comment: Just emphasizing here that although many docs tell you how to install a separate ftp server, actually once you have ssh server running you can connect to that with sftp clients like Filezilla (using same credentials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Ubuntu Software Center**

Search for `openssh-server` in software center. Server related programs may not be shown in default search results in the Software Center. You may have to make sure that technical results are visible in the search. There should be a link at the bottom of the Software Center window with the words "Show *nnn* technical items," where *nnn* is a number.

**Using the Command line**

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Unlike the GUI, the password prompt won't show anything like **** when you type the password. This is normal.

The two methods of installing software in Ubuntu do exactly the same thing. A lot of people write command line methods in answers because they are easy to copy and paste in the terminal and easy to describe. The server installation does not have the desktop, so only command line works for both type of installation.

**For FTP server:**

I recommend using `sftp`. This is more secure than ftp and is part of ssh. So you won't need another server. Another advantage of `sftp` is, if you setup private/public key based login for ssh, the same system will work for sftp.

Otherwise there are many ftp servers you can choose from. I think making sure the "technical results" are visible will show them if you type ftp.

see [Basic Ubuntu FTP Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1722/basic-ubuntu-ftp-server) and [How do I install a FTP Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323868/how-do-i-install-a-ftp-server) for various other ftp servers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

I prefer `scp` over ftp

Comment: Short and correct answer, but first answer was more complete. But i will vote up for usefull answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH
- [Ubuntu LTS Server guide on FTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html)
- http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-an-FTP-Server-in-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here too: 
http://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: Thanks for the links anyway. I will upvote for helpfull answer.